# Express.js - Connect with GraphQL external API

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, graphql

I have problem with connect to external API (GraphQL) on Express.js . Can You give me a some good tutorials about this?

And one more question. I have this error:

[Link to error message - img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CLcz.png)

It's possible to connect with this API ?

Comment: server should white list the caller ip address . look up `CORS`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following middleware to your NodeJS/Express app (I have added some comments for your convenience):

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Hope that helps!